# Did the USA or EU ever give out any statement about the communal riots and pogroms that take place in India on an almost yearly basis?

Tags: united-states, european-union, india

As far as I understand, the international community has a great deal of respect for the Republic of India, its history, its culture, and its people given the frequency at which Indian PM/presidents are given opportunities to address in their parliaments:

- [Modi addresses the US Congress](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gImWTYhKhOA)
- [Modi addresses the British parliament](https://youtu.be/x1nw9-x_Oy8)
- [Modi addresses the Australian parliament](https://youtu.be/w6SG3Hy5KbQ)
- [APJ Abdul Kalam addresses EU parliament](https://youtu.be/xE4azJ-wro4)

However, the Republic of India has many problems, including religious or communal divides and tensions that over the years have given rise to numerous communal riots and pogroms.

- [Religious pogroms in India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_violence_in_India#Statistics)

When someone tries to assess a country, these elements should also naturally come into consideration.

Did the USA or EU ever give out any statement about the communal riots and pogroms that take place in India on an almost yearly basis, some of which are purposefully [designed to impress voters to win elections](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304387817301025)?

Comment: Expecting people to go to outside sources and watch videos to understand your question isn't going to help you get a good response. There are likely others like me who would like to learn more about the question you are asking but don't have time to invest in watching multiple videos of speeches being given.

Comment: Isn't rioting an internal affair? It is not like the government circling the ethnic/religious minority and harming them.

Comment: @r13, *It is not like the government circling the ethnic/religious minority and harming them.* --- do you know that Indian political parties incite religious violence on purpose to buy Hindu voter's sympathy?

Comment: I don't know much about India, but I guess the situation has been deemed as an internal conflict/unrest rather than a human right violation, or religious persecution.

Comment: @r13, how about the ruling party bjp inciting and financing riots in 2002 and in 2020?

Comment: This seems to be arguing against a specific political cause. While Politics SE is less scientific than, say, Chemistry SE, it is not a discussion board.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the United States and European nations have, on several occasions, commented on riots or pogroms in India, though perhaps not with great frequency.

A few examples:

- In 2020, in the wake of riots in New Delhi, the US government [called for](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.outlookindia.com/website/story/india-news-delhi-riots-us-urges-india-to-protect-and-respect-right-to-peaceful-assembly/347981/amp) the freedom of expression of peaceful protesters to be protected, condemned the violence, and said that violent rioters should be held accountable.
- Several US state governments have passed official resolutions against the [1984 anti-Sikh riots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1984_anti-Sikh_riots?wprov=sfla1), as noted on the Wikipedia page.
- The European Union [called for](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/asia-pacific/eu-calls-for-probe-into-police-role-in-delhi-riots/1998701) an investigation into police involvement in riots in New Delhi in 2020.
- The EU also [condemned the 2002 Gujarat riots.](https://m.rediff.com/news/2002/may/18train.htm) That said, later on, as EU-India relations improved, an EU envoy would absolve Modi of responsibility for the riots.

Comment: seems to be insufficient amount of statements given the sheer number of religious riots and pogroms take place in india.