# Do Muslim countries other than Pakistan officially protest when there are anti-Muslim riots in India? More so than "the West"?

Tags: international-relations, india, comparative-politics, islam, minorities

As a companion to [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/75204/did-the-usa-or-eu-ever-give-out-any-statement-about-the-communal-riots-and-pogro) are there examples of official protests (or calls for investigations etc.) by Muslim countries other than Pakistan when anti-Muslim riots happen in India?

Most interesting would be joint/consensus declarations like from the Arab League, the Organization of Turkic States, the Organisation of Islamic Cooperation etc.

And if it's somehow possible to quantify this, do Islamic countries (other than Pakistan) protest more often against India on such riot/violence matters compared to "the West"? (Blasphemy excluded, I did find some of [those](https://edition.cnn.com/2022/06/06/middleeast/india-islam-comments-gulf-mime-intl/index.html) protests, which didn't seem to have a US/EU official counterpart.)

Comment: This question is asked in bad faith, the author of this question is an expert on this topic. So, I voted to close. This is a push question. Though, a minor answer would be yes. Almost Everytime. The protests were by OIC. I would not say riots were frequent. But if they felt anything anti-Islamic, there were protests by OIC.

Comment: @Gary2: what makes you think I'm an expert in protests by the Arab League, the OIC etc.?

Comment: BTW, my google search for ["islamic countries protest against india"](https://www.google.com/search?q=islamic+countries+protest+against+india) returns almost nothing other than the June 6-13 2022 (BJP spokesperson triggering protests) on the first page. Google is just too optimized for recent events nowadays :-(

Comment: Do you strictly want riots?

Comment: I think the expertise of the author of this question is singularly irrelevant.  The purpose of all the Stack Exchange sites is to build up a body of useful questions and answers.  The author actually knowing something about a topic doesn't conflict with that goal.

Comment: @Gary2 I dont see anything all that pushy.  Similar questions have been asked about Muslim countries' diplomatic communications to China wrt Uyghurs.  The question itself is worded neutrally and the info is not common knowledge to many users, I'd guess.  It is also not uncommon for a bloc to play up complaints about a particular subject to one audience but then ignore a similar problem elsewhere because it suits them to do so diplomatically.

Comment: @Fizz you get some filtering by picking `Tools` at the right end of top result line, then pick `Custom date range` from the leftmost, `Any time` column.  Then specify a date in the 2nd, `To`, date criteria.   The problem is that sometimes pages seem to get refreshed with "recent markers" when something or another is inject next to the article page.  Which results in older news not showing up because they "look newer" to Google.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- [Delhi Riots Diplomatic Fallout: India Tackles Criticism From Iran, UK, Turkey](https://thewire.in/external-affairs/delhi-riots-iran-uk-turkey)

In 2020, on the occasion of the Delhi Riot, Turkey and Iran criticized India so much that India had to summon the ambasadors to rebuke them.

---

Regarding other Muslim-majority countries:

- Central Asia: they seemingly can not care less as they maintain a different standard of mindset. They even have long-standing diplomatic relations with Israel.
- Gulf countries: historically and in modern times, heavily dependent on India in terms of oil and other trade. Some states even have an Indian population greater than the natives, e.g., UAE and Bahrain.
- South East Asian countries: Malaysia is heavily dependent on India for palm oil trade. Also, they have a local Tamil population who have great sympathy for and connection with India. Regarding Indonesia, their culture is half-Hindu. Many Indonesians even have Hindu names.
- Noth Africa: mostly dictator-ruled. Morocco has an agnostic policy regarding IR as they have diplomatic relations with Israel. Egypt has historical relations with India due to Nasser. I personally talked to Egyptians; they have an utterly negative connotation of India. I saw some Egyptian food shops behave badly toward Indians.
- Afganistan, Iraq, Yemen, etc.: I personally talked to these people. They are dependent on India for medical tourism and higher education as their own countries are devastated. However, they are also addicted to Indian movies. Therefore, they have a very positive attitude toward India.

Comment: The OIC also said something in April 2020 (via Twitter apparently, given the hashtags), that it "urges the #Indian Govt to take urgent steps to stop the growing tide of #Islamophobia in India" https://www.aa.com.tr/en/asia-pacific/oic-body-urges-india-to-halt-islamophobia-amid-covid-19/1811429 So they might have said something (more specific) about the riot a month earlier, but I could not find that insofar.

Comment: Many Islamic countries such as Egypt and Indonesia have historic links with India through the [Non-aligned movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Aligned_Movement) in the Cold War and after (since the Islamic Revolution there, Iran has been prominent).

Comment: Found something more explicit said by OIC in Oct 2021 about violence in Assam  https://tribune.com.pk/story/2324037/oic-rebukes-india-over-systematic-persecution-of-muslims-in-assam Again in Feb 2022 https://www.arabnews.com/node/2024791/world although that's more about hijab. I think tentatively it's fair to say even the OIC said more than "the West".

Comment: @Fizz, If you search *Nupur Sharma & Naveen Jindal* incident, you will find more.

Comment: Yes, you can chalk me up as a rather "clueless Westerner" when it comes topics like these. That's why I'm asking questions like these. (I don't read OIC pressers on a daily [or even yearly] basis either, as another commenter was somehow quick to "infer".)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Take for example the recent criticism of [BJP party member Nupur Sharma on Prophet Mohammad](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-61716241). As a result many GCC countries like [Kuwait](https://indianexpress.com/article/india/kuwait-superstore-removes-indian-products-after-prophet-remark-7956139/), [Saudi](https://theprint.in/world/calls-to-boycott-indian-goods-grow-as-derogatory-remarks-on-prophet-riles-middle-east/988753/) etc have boycotted against India.

An additional remark I can put is that this was a very bad move for India as they import more than 70% of their oil, and Gulf is one of the regions they import from. [Source](https://www.thequint.com/news/india/prophet-remarks-row-why-the-gulf-is-crucial-for-india-bjp-nupur-sharma-qatar-iran-iraq-saudi-arabia-trade-oil)

Comment: The OP asked about riots. ***Nupur Sharma*** incident was not a riot.

Comment: Well, that incident was known to me. As I was doing some preliminary research on the Q, that incident flooded my google searches... (there's a link to an article about it in the Q.)